# Split Data and order columns

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying some split-apply-combine methods. How do I split a data into different categories and then sort each categories on descending order of a particular column.

First I split mtcars

```
spmtcars <-split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

then if I do

```
sort_mtc <- spmtcars[order(mpg), ]
```

> Error in order(mpg) : object 'mpg' not found

According to the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579672/re-order-data-after-split-in-r), I will have to use `sapply` I am not sure how.

Comment: If you want to use those commands in particular, you can order the data before you split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `lapply`

```
lapply(spmtcars, function(x) x[order(-x$mpg),])
```